# Why are the following events independent in this example?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Suppose an integer is picked at random from the set $\{1,2,3,...,36\}$. Let $A_{n}$ be the event "the chosen integer is a multiple of $n$". Consider events $A_{3}$, $A_{4}$, and $A_{6}$. We have:

$P(A_{3}) = \frac{12}{36} = \frac{1}{3}, \quad$  $P(A_{4}) = \frac{9}{36} = \frac{1}{4}, \quad$ and $P(A_{6}) = \frac{6}{36} = \frac{1}{6}$.

Now $P(A_{3} \cap A_{4}) = \frac{3}{36} = \frac{1}{12} = P(A_{3})P(A_{4})$, hence $A_{3}$ and $A_{4}$ are independent.

But, we have that $P(A_{4} \cap A_{6}) = \frac{3}{36} = \frac{1}{12} \neq P(A_{4})P(A_{6})$, so $A_{4}$ and $A_{6}$ are not independent. Why is this the case ? What is the fundamental difference that leads to $A_{3}$ and $A_{4}$ being independent, but not $A_{4}$ and $A_{6}$ ?

Answer (score 2):

First, I think that conceptually, it is a little more helpful to think about two events $A$ and $B$ being independent not so much as:

$P(A \cap B) = P(A) \times P(B)$

but rather as:

$P(A|B) = P(A|B') = P(A)$

That is: $A$ and $B$ are independent if the presence (or absence) of $B$ makes no difference on the likelihood of $A$

Now, as a *consequence* of this, you have that:

$P(A \cap B) \overset{Always \ True!}{=} P(A|B)\times P(B) \overset{Independence}{=}P(A) \times P(B)$

OK, so thinking about it this way, we can explain the independence of $A_3$ and $A_4$ basically because $3$ and $4$ are relatively prime, which means that out of all the numbers that are divisible by $3$, a quarter are also divisible by $4$, and that is exactly the ratio of all numbers divisible by $4$. As such: whether a number is divisible by $3$ has no effect on whether a  number is divisible by $4$, i.e. $P(A_4|A_3) = P(A_4)$, making them independent.

On the other hand,  $4$ and $6$ have a common factor $2$, making $A_4$ and $A_6$ dependent: Tthe event $A_4$ means that you picked an even number, and that makes the event $A_6$ more likely than if you don’t know anything about the picked number. That is: $P(A_6|A_4) > P(A_6)$, making them dependent.

Of course, my reasoning here so far has been assuming that you randomly pick a number from *all* natural numbers, and that is not the case here, since you pick a number out of only the first $36$ numbers.  As such, while the numbers $3$ and $5$ are also relatively prime, you won;t find that $P(A_5|A_3) = P(A_5)$, because $3$ and $5$ will 'co-cycle' every $15$ numbers, and with $36$ not being a multiple of $15$, one or the other will be represented just slightly more than the other. So ... $P(A_5|A_3)$ will probably be pretty close to $P(A_5)$ (closer than $P(A_6|A_4)$ will be to $P(A_6)$), but it won;t be exact. Of course, if you had $45$ numbers to pick from, you *will* find that $P(A_5|A_3) = P(A_5)$, but now $P(A_4|A_3)$ will no longer equal $P(A_4)$, since $45$ is not a common multiple of both $3$ and $4$.

Comment: Thank you. But what about $A_{3}$ and $A_{5}$? $3$ and $5$ are relatively prime, but $P(A_{3} \cap A_{5} = \frac{1}{18} \neq P(A_{3})P(A_{5})$...? @Bram28

Comment: P.S. Another thing. Say I picked a multiple of $4$. Now  some multiples of $4$ are also multiples of $3$, and hence event $A_{4}$ makes event $A_{3}$ more likely too, doesn't it? @Bram28

Comment: @sasha1001 For $A_3$ and $A_5$: these ‘cycle’ around every $15$, and$36$ is not amultiple of $15$. But $A_3$ and $A_4$ cycle around every $12$, and $36$ is smultiple of $12$

Comment: @sasha1001 yes, some multiples of $3$ are multiples if $4$, but others are not. And again, since they are relatively prime (and since $36$ is a nice multiple of $12$), you will find that exactly one quarter of all multiples of $3$ are a multiple of $4$… which is exactly the ratio of *all* numbers that are a multiple of $4$